# Accidentally resized a partition with Parted, can't mount it anymore

Tags: linux, partitioning

One hour ago I tried to resize a ext4 partition in a rescue system with parted, but I decided not to do it. I tried to leave it without saving but when I fixed the problem otherwise, I tried to boot the new OS (openSUSE Tumbleweed) but the ext4 partition seems to be destroyed. Probably it's only the partition table but I don't know how to revert it. Help me please, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). It can research and recover lost partitions successfully most of the time. Avoid to do anything else on the disk before recovery, otherwise recovery chance might be reduced.

Comment: Thank you, much easier than I expected! I tried another similar program before which gave me a weird error message so I was a bit worried, but it's booting perfectly now.